# Is there any difference between wholewheat pasta and wholewheat sphaghetti besides the shape?

Tags: pasta, spaghetti, wholewheat

I'm asking about the plain food as you would buy from the shop which has no extra ingredients.  It seems to me they are both pure wheat just in different shapes.  Is that correct or has one been processed more than the other in any way which may have caused nutrient loss?

Comment: You could read the nutrition on the package.

Answer (score 4):

Spaghetti is a type of pasta. "Pasta" is generally used as a generic term for Italian noodles; you can see more shapes of pasta [here](https://pastafits.org/pasta-dictionary/). If the ingredients are the same, the processing is likely the same––most dried pasta is just flour and water.